# How to run cross-platform application as a service?

Tags: asp.net-core, cross-platform

I am developing .NET Core cross-platform console application. It is gRPC service.
Is it possible to run it this way:

> myapp -service

and if flag is set

```
1. if (OS == Windows) app should run itself as a Windows service
2. if (OS == Linux or MAC) app should run itself as a daemon
```

Comment: https://www.wintellect.com/creating-a-daemon-with-net-core-part-1/

Comment: Thanx. The same code works in Windows, Linux, MAC OS?

Comment: I believe so but haven't tested it.